# Trying to get pyramid to print n amount of x's in java error

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input any positive integer ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t");

        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            System.out.println(" ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print("X");

        System.out.println();
    }
    input.close();
}
```

So basically i'm trying to get it to print a pyramid such like this but flipped:

1 x

2 xx

3 xxx

I want it for any number the user desires, but my output is totally messed up. I can do it when the pyramid is show like above but not mirrored (which i need). What am I doing doing wrong?

Comment: *hint:*  your loop variable doesn't have to start with 1 and you don't have to use `++` and `<=`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input any positive integer ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sb.append("X");
    }

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", i, sb.toString()));
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: While this code works, i guess i was not clear enough. I wanted it to mirror instead, probably should have been more clear. Thank you very much though!

Comment: @F.ochoa15 You definitely were not very clear. You could easily achieve a mirror effect with the code I have supplied you with a only few minor changes. Happy coding.

Comment: While your code works it may be helpful to explain it. Especially the later stuff could get be confusing if one is not familiar with it.